# Using .OrderByDescending

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I have no idea how to do this, and I am hoping that it's pretty simple stuff, all I want to do is order these results by timestamp, but I have no idea where to drop the .OrderByDescending that doesn't throw an error.

```
public List<EmployerObject> My(string username)
    {
        return client.Cypher
            .Match("(person:Person)-[worked:WORKED_AT]->(employer:Employer)-[:IN_TOWN]-(town)-[:IN_CITY]-(city)-[:IN_STATE]-(state)-[:IN_COUNTRY]-(country)")
            .Where((Person person) => person.Email == username)
            .Return((person, employer, worked, town, city, state, country) => new EmployerObject
            {
                Person = person.As<Person>(),
                Employer = employer.CollectAs<Employer>(),
                Worked = worked.CollectAs<Worked>(),
                Town = town.CollectAs<Town>(),
                City = city.CollectAs<City>(),
                State = state.CollectAs<State>(),
                Country = country.CollectAs<Country>()
            })
            .Results.ToList();
```

I want to sort by 'worked.startDate' (C# long), I have been told it is possible to do the sort and then cast the resulting object as an EmployerObject, but that makes little sense.
Using Neo4j 2.2.5, and 2 versions of the client (for different areas of the project, one from NuGet downloaded this week and another as git source but I cannot for the life of me work out the version number, so a solution for either is acceptable).

Any help is good help, thanks.

Comment: Have you put the `OrderBy` after the `Return` but before `Results` i.e.: `Return (/**/).OrderBy(/**/).Results` - and what is the error you're getting?

Comment: If I use worked.StartDate I get worked does not exist in the current context, if I quote it then I get the worked is not defined when I execute the service.

Comment: To clarify using. Orderbydescending(worked. startDate) it won't compile, if I use. Orderbydescending("worked.StartDate") it compiles but errors when we run the script.

Comment: But `worked` is a `CollectAs` statement, so technically it doesn't have a `StartDate` property - sooo - what is the end result you want? Do you want  an `EmployerObject` instance, with the `Worked` property ordered by `StartDate` ?

Comment: Yes, that is the end result I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, the secret sauce you need is the `WITH` statement, the following code should work for you:

```
return client.Cypher
    .Match("(person:Person)-[worked:WORKED_AT]->(employer:Employer)-[:IN_TOWN]-(town)-[:IN_CITY]-(city)-[:IN_STATE]-(state)-[:IN_COUNTRY]-(country)")
    .Where((Person person) => person.Email == username)
    .With("person, worked, employer") //<-- New Line!
    .OrderBy("worked.StartDate")      //<-- New Line!
    .Return((person, employer, worked, town, city, state, country) => new EmployerObject
    {
        Person = person.As<Person>(),
        Employer = employer.CollectAs<Employer>(),
        Worked = worked.CollectAs<Worked>(),
        Town = town.CollectAs<Town>(),
        City = city.CollectAs<City>(),
        State = state.CollectAs<State>(),
        Country = country.CollectAs<Country>()
    })
    .Results.ToList();
```

As for the why - the `WITH` statement allows you to chain the results of one query to another, you can kind of think of it as a `RETURN` in the middle of your query - allowing you to perform operations on your data you wouldn't be able to until after a `RETURN` (such as `ORDER BY`).